# Eclipse: Way for force updating/rebuilding from a build or classpath file?

Tags: eclipse, build, classpath

Eclipse 3.8.2

I'm working on a large project in Eclipse, composed of dozens of Eclipse plugins.  I did a Team > Update > Head to get a fresh set of code down.  I then did a clean and build, but got many errors.

I had several "build path invalid" errors, that a team mate helped me fix by instructing to open up some build, classpath and manifest files, typing a blank space, removing the space, and saving.

That forced eclipse to take another look at those files and reset things, making the errors go away.

My question is, is there an automatic way to make eclipse look at those kind files without having to to trick it into doing so?

Comment: Are you using ivy as dependency management tool? Then you should hit 'Resolve All'. That should help!

Comment: I don't think so, the project uses ANT.  How can I tell if the project uses Ivy?

Comment: Are there ivy.xml files in your project?

Comment: None that I can see, just ANT xmls

Answer (score 1):

Closing and reopening the projects can often help.